# Appending Every two columns into single column from same table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

```
dt1    transaction_1   dt2   transaction_2   dt3   transaction_3....dt80 tra_80
may01    22            jun01    56           Aug09   73
sep02    49            feb12    53           dec23   80
```

Now the Should be like below

```
dt      transaction        type
may01    22             transaction_1  
sep02    49             transaction_1   
jun01    56             transaction_2
feb12    53              transaction_2
Aug09    73              transaction_3
dec23    80              transaction_3
....     ..             ......
....     ..             ......
```

....     ..              transaction_80
Plz anyone provide Query in MYSQL.
thanks,

Comment: select concat(column1, ' ', column2)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function `CONCAT(string1, string2)`
example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(dt, transaction) FROM table_name
```